# How do I use xmlTextReader to extract values?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xmlreader

I'm trying to parse this XML for the values of puppies and kittens.

```
<Pets>
    <Puppies>4</Puppies>
    <Kittens>2</Kittens>
</Pets>
```

Here's my code

```
        baseReader = New IO.StringReader(testXml)
        xmlReader = New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(baseReader)

        While xmlReader.Read()

        Select Case xmlReader.Name
            Case "Puppies"
                puppyCount = CLng(xmlReader.ReadInnerXml)
            Case "Kittens"
                kittenCount = CLng(xmlReader.ReadInnerXml)
            Case Else

        End Select
        End While
```

On the first read, the element name is "Pets" and the Case Else gets hit. On the next read, the element name is "Puppies" and puppyCount is correctly set to 4.

But then it seems to skip over "Kittens" and go directly to the inner XML. What should I be doing?

EDIT: XmlReader is faster than other .NET parsers, but my files are small enough that it's probably not a benefit. [Joe Ferner's tests.](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html)

EDIT 2: There's a reader positioning problem in the original code.

Comment: Why you don't use `XmlDocument/XPath/XDocument`?

Comment: I'm reading my entire document every time, so a forward-only reader works fine.

Comment: You should not be using `new XmlTextReader()`. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Comment: Why is that? I'm curious, not being flip.

Comment: @Thalecress, see this link for why to use `Create` over `new`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9khb6435.aspx

Comment: @Thal: `XmlReader.Create()` was introduced in .NET 2.0, and provides far more flexibility than `new XmlTextReder()`. In particular, buy using the Factory Pattern, it stands a much better chance of creating an instance of the best type of `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless performance is really important, I would suggest using LINQ to XML:

```
Dim elem = XElement.Parse(testXml)

Dim puppyCount = CType(elem.Element("Puppies").Value, integer)
Dim kittenCount = CType(elem.Element("Kittens").Value, integer)
```

Comment: Additionally,    Dim puppyCount = CType(elem.Descendants("Puppies").Value, integer) works even if <Puppies> was more than one element deep from <Pets>

Comment: Yes, it does work, but I prefer to as precise as possible. If the structure of the XML changed, I think it's better to fail loudly than to do something that might be subtly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I struck the same problem with both `XMLTextReade`r and `XMLReader`.  The original problem is that `.ReadInnerXML()` can sometimes perform an end-of-line read, and then then at the top of the loop you do another read which of course means you've skipped the next element.  You can try using `.ReadString` instead - this worked for me.